# 'System.InvalidOperationException' in TabControl

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

```
<Window x:Class="AutoMerge2013.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="AutoMerge2013" Height="350" Width="525"
    Style="{StaticResource VS2012WindowStyle}">
    <TabControl x:Name="tbControl">
    <TabItem Header="Main">
        <Canvas>
            <Button Name="btnOpen" Content="Open files" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="20" Width="98" Click="btnOpen_Click_1"/>
            <Button Name="btnUpload" Content="Upload files" Canvas.Left="181" Canvas.Top="20" Width="98" Visibility="Hidden" Click="btnUpload_Click_1"/>
            <Button Name="btnMerge" Content="AutoMerge" Canvas.Left="338" Canvas.Top="20" Width="98" Visibility="Hidden" Click="btnMerge_Click_1"/>


            <StatusBar Canvas.Top="247" Width="499">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtInfo"></TextBlock>
                <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <ResizeGrip />
                </StatusBarItem>
            </StatusBar>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Original">

    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

When I click the Original tab it throws an exeption:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: The specified Visual is not a descendant of this Visual.

I use in my application `Style="{StaticResource VS2012WindowStyle}"`
Maybe it is an issue...
Can you give some advise how to avoid this exception and save my style ?

Comment: What's the definition of `VS2012WindowStyle`?

Comment: Also you haven't closed your `<Canvas>` element. Is this just a cut and paste error when creating your question or is your code really like this?

Comment: thanx for your feedback
it is just an error when the copy-paste process. I pasted the main part of xaml murkup

the VS2012WindowStyle is the next:

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/frhnai1h4wmhjb2/VS2012WindowStyle.cs?m)

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/znx1qzab98zcjbw/VS2012WindowStyle.xaml?m)

Comment: Don't paste links to code. Just include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: VS2012WindowStyle describes appearance of my controls...but there are no descriptions for TabControl and TabItem. Maybe it is an issue...
if yes can you please give me an advise how to add the descriptions for TabControl and TabItem correctly?